# var attribute echoed with php and not submitted from form

Tags: php, jquery

Using this

```
`$(function(){$(".signaler").click(function(){var element=$(this);var I = element.attr("id");var page = $('#page').attr('value');var info = "id="+I+"& page="+ page;$("#signaler"+I).hide();$("#load"+I).html('<img class="think" src="load.gif" >');$.ajax({type:"POST",url:"signaler.php",data:info,success:function(){$("#load"+I).empty();$("#ok"+I).fadeIn(200).show();}});return false;});});`
```

but have a form with hidden inputs only so i can echo current user info into it, was wondering if I could put it straight into jquery? Working fine though.

With a form you would use the following

`var page=$('#page').attr('value');`

I would like to set the id with php echoing user name/id..

Something like `var id=$('<?php echo $user/$id... ?>');`

If someone could point out the right jquery syntax, would be very greatful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var id = $(<?= $_POST["whatever_it_was"] ?>)`

Comment: this needs quotes doesn't it? $("<?php $_POST["whatever_it_was"] ?>")

Comment: likely... but backticks or singles since I used doubles inside

Answer (score 0):

pretty much what you used as an example...

```
<?php echo $user . '/' . $id ?>
```

As long as the file in question is being parsed as php by the server that is...

Comment: sorry that was an example literally! one or other doesn't matter. Edited question, am I more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should get the value of a form input using the `val()` method:

```
$('input#id').val();
```

Then on the PHP side if you `POST` to the page using AJAX then do:

```
'var id=$('<?php echo $_POST['user'] . '/' . $_POST['id'] ?>')';
```

Comment: I have a form with hidden inputs only. So i can echo current user info into it, was wondering if I could put it straight into jquery? Working fine though. Edited it above.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is essentially a string you wish to use for somewhere in you jQuery. Well in that case what you have is essentially correct. If in your PHP file you do (notice the quotation marks:

```
var id = "<?php echo $yourId ?>";
```

You can then use that variable (which holds your PHP string) normally. The following would for example select the element with the id in the variable `id`:

```
$('#' + id)
```